# Return Only Selected Columns From SharePoint List using Graph API and Transform Graph.List to DataTable

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

So I'm new to Graph API, and working with my team on writing a utility to authenticate users to allow access to files and lists on our new SharePoint Online environment. The authentication side is working and we are now looking to add the functionality to return data from existing lists.
This is a two part question, only because whilst I can return the selected columns from an on-premise SharePoint list, it's not working the same for an Online list.
We have set up a test list on our online test site, and I'm using the following to return a defined set of columns:

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
        {
            new QueryOption("select", "LinkTitle,Project_x0020_Title1,Client_x0020_Hub_x0020_ID,ClientType")
        };

        var items = await graphService.GetAuthenticatedClient().Sites[siteId].Lists[listId]
            .Request(queryOptions)
            .GetAsync();
```

Although I'm only selecting four columns, it is returning the full column count for this list (which is 20). Is there a way to only select and return the columns I want?

The second part of the question relates to converting the resulting data from the Graph API call (which returns a Graph.List) to a DataTable.
It appears that there is no enumerator for Graph.List, so I'm unsure how to iterate through the list and convert it to a datatable (which I can then use with existing code for one of the tools this is being written for).

If I amend the following line to append .Items to the end:

```
var items = await graphService.GetAuthenticatedClient().Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items
            .Request(queryOptions)
            .GetAsync();
```

this returns an IListItemsCollectionPage, and whilst this can be converted to a DataTable using code found online i.e.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)...
```

The data isn't being returned as I'd expect.

Any help on one or both part of this question, gratefully received!

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0):

OK, so looking at this again, it jut needed a different approach!

```
 var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
        {
            new QueryOption("expand", "fields(select=LinkTitle,Project_x0020_Title,Client_x0020_Hub_x0020_ID,ClientType)")
        };
```

...

```
var dt = new DataTable("DataTable");
        dt.Columns.Add("LinkTitle");
        dt.Columns.Add("Project_x0020_Title");
        dt.Columns.Add("Client_x0020_Hub_x0020_ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("ClientType");
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.BeginEdit();
            dr["LinkTitle"] = item.Fields.AdditionalData["LinkTitle"];
            dr["Project_x0020_Title"] = item.Fields.AdditionalData["Project_x0020_Title"];
            dr["Client_x0020_Hub_x0020_ID"] = item.Fields.AdditionalData["Client_x0020_Hub_x0020_ID"];
            dr["ClientType"] = item.Fields.AdditionalData["ClientType"];
            dr.EndEdit();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

This returns a datatable with the correct columns and data, so changing the queryoptions got me the data!
Thanks
Martin